# Smooth points dominated by discrete valuation rings

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $k$ be a finitely generated field over $\mathbb{Q}$ and let $S$ be a smooth model of $k.$ If $s \in S$ is a closed point, I have seen the statement that there exists a discrete valuation $v$ whose valuation ring $R_v$ dominates $\mathcal{O}_{S,s}$ and such that $R_v$ has the same residue field as $\mathcal{O}_{S,s}.$

How can one show that this is true? I tried to blow-up in $s,$ but that doesn't seem to allow me to conclude.

Comment: In the two-dimensional case, with local parameters $x,y$ at $s$, consider $\mathcal{O}_{S, s}\to k(s)[[x,y]]\to k(s)[[t]]$ where the second map sends $x$ to $t$ and $y$ to some transcendental $f(t)$, e.g. ${\rm exp}(t)-1$. It is easy to generalize this to more variables.